They would/will have been married forty years come this June

They would have been married forty years come this June.

'would have pp' means past,but 'come this June' implies future.
What's the meaning of the example sentence and what about 'will' insteand of 'would' in the sentence?

They will have been married forty years come this June.


Would have: they will not be married next June, but could have been if something had not happened, e.g. they will be divorced or one or both are dead. Will have: they are still married at the time of speaking. My childhood pet cat Millie would have been 61 years old next September; my current pet cat Keir will have been my pet for two years this December.

"Would" is used here to give a conditional sense, rather than a particular tense.  The implication is that the condition is counterfactual.  That is they will not have been married for 40 years, but would have been (if some event had been different).  The mostly common situation to use this is if one or both of the people have died.

Mary will celebrate her anniversary alone again this year.  She and her husband, Ted, would have been married for forty year years come June. Unfortunately, Ted died in a car accident 25 years ago.

The use of "will" isn't counterfactual.  It asserts that in June they will still be married, and their wedding was in June 40 years ago.

Is this the Perfect Continuous Conditional?

"Would have been doing"   is continuous.

As the only things that can end a marriage are death or divorce, if someone said "they would have been married for 40 years", I'd take that to mean that either one of them died or they got divorced.

@jay or possibly they never got married in the first place  "Mary and Ted met at high school and planned to marry as soon as they graduated.  They would have been married for forty years now, but Ted got cold feet...."

@JamesK Fair enough.

But why do we have to use one of the most tragic examples in the answer?

@Barmar In terms of efficiency, it may very well put us "in context."

@Barmar because that's the only context that makes sense? The second I saw the title it immediately invoked "well, that implies someone died". The only other way out of marriage is divorce and, in that case, why would you even make such a remark? "I would have still been driving to this day if I hadn't reached my destination, parked up and stepped out of the car". It doesn't make sense; you just wouldn't make such comments outside of a tragic/unexpected termination of the situation
